# Azure CLI bash loop not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, azure

I'm trying to learn bash and become less PowerShell dependent but running into issues with what seems like an easy loop.

Below is my attempt to get the loop to return each VM result with it's associated name, id, and tag.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
#Get a list of VMs with their name, id, and tags from Azure 
r=$(az vm list -g lab.rg1 --query "[].{name:name, id:id, tags:tags}") #--output tsv)

#take that list and do something. Currently just trying to echo each VM with it's name,id, and tags.
while read r
do
    echo $r
done

echo All Done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while read variable` construct doesn't read *from* `variable`, it iterates over its input and stores each record *as* `variable`. So you can do something like this:

```
command | while read r; do something with "$r"; done
```

or this:

```
while read r; do something with "$r"; done < file
```

In your case, you don't need the `$r` variable at all, try this instead:

```
az vm list -g lab.rg1 --query "[].{name:name, id:id, tags:tags}" |
  while read r
  do
     echo "$r"
  done
echo All Done
```

If you absolutely must use the `$r` variable, you could do:

```
r=$(az vm list -g lab.rg1 --query "[].{name:name, id:id, tags:tags}")

## print the value of the variable and pass that to the loop
printf '%s\n' "$r" |
  while read line
  do
     echo "$line"
  done
echo All Done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I eliminated the $r variable and I was able to echo the results as I'd expect.

However, when I try to run the command as follows, I get that the id is wrong.



`
az vm list -g lab.rg1 --query "[].{name:name, id:id, tags:tags}" |
 while read r
  do
     az tag update --resource-id $r.id --operation Merge --tags Backup=Yes
     echo "$r"
  done
echo All Done
`

Comment: @Braden please ask a new question, include the output of the a command so we know what you are trying to read and show the new command. We can't really understand from the comments.

Comment: Thanks I did [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769931/bash-loop-help-returning-value-from-query)